# Integral $\int^{\infty}_{- \infty} e^{z(a+t)} \frac{1}{(e^z + 1)^{a+b}} dz$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to compute the following integral, but I have no idea how to proceed. I have simplified the function down to the following as shown below, but I do not know how to proceed.

$$\int^{\infty}_{- \infty} e^{z(a+t)} \frac{1}{(e^z + 1)^{a+b}} * \frac{1}{B(a,b)} dz$$

For reference, $a, b$ are positive real number, $z$ is a real number (positive or negative), and $B$ is the beta function.

How can I evaluate this integral?

Comment: Just to double-check, there are separate values $a,b,t,z$ in the integral you intend to evaluate, correct?

Comment: @abiessu just treat them as constants. z is the main variable

Comment: Use $x=1-\tfrac{1}{1+e^z}$ (i.e. $z=\ln\tfrac{x}{1-x}$) to write it as a Beta function.

Comment: @user839334: I understand, but the evaluation could be much simpler if $b=t$.

Comment: @abiessu unfortunately, they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically J.G.'s answer from the comments.

Let $\displaystyle x=\frac{e^z}{e^z+1}$ (equaling $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{e^z+1}$) which ranges over $(0,1)$ as $z$ ranges over $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Then $\displaystyle \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}z}\mathrm{d}z=\frac{e^z}{(e^z+1)^2}\mathrm{d}z=x(1-x)\mathrm{d}z$ and the integral (ignoring $\displaystyle\frac{1}{B(a,b)}$) becomes

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{z(a+t)}}{(e^z+1)^{a+b}}\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^z}{e^z+1}\right)^{a+t} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(e^z+1)^{b-t}} $$

$$ =\int_0^1 x^{a+t}(1-x)^{b-t}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(1-x)}=B(a+t,b-t). $$

Therefore, remembering the original $B(a,b)$, the answer is

$$ \frac{B(a+t,b-t)}{B(a,b)}. $$